# How to get selected value in combo box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a form like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/Fkwa3/).

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
<select name="mydropdown">
<option value="A">AAA</option>
<option value="B">BBB</option>
<option value="C">CCC</option>
</select>
</form>
```

For radio buttons I would do

```
var type = $(this).find('input:radio[name="ctype"]:checked').val() || '';
```

but this can't I get to work on combo boxes.

How can I get the value of the selected option in a combo box?

**Update**

It is called on a webpage with many forms, so I need the selected value from `this` particular combo box.

Here is how I get the values from text boxes and radio buttons.

```
$('form').live('submit', function(){

   var title = this.elements.title.value;
   var type  = $(this).find('input:radio[name="ctype"]:checked').val() || '';
   var sect  = ?

   ...
```

Comment: I was about to find a duplicate of this and close it, but I at amazed how many **different** answers it got in such a short time.  Most of them were wrong and have been edited, but congrats @leandre_b on some watershed rep for getting it right first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply :

```
$('select[name="mydropdown"]').val();
```

UPDATE:

And when inside one of the forms :

```
$('form').live('submit', function(){

   var value_of_dropdown  = $(this).find('select[name="mydropdown"]').val();

   ...
```

Comment: I have updated the post to be more precise. I need it on a webpage with more than one form. So when the submit button is pressed I need the selected value from `this` combo box.

Answer (score 1):

For select boxes its enough to use `val()` to get the selected value.

```
$('select[name="mydropdown"]').val();
```

**EDIT:** I edited the response because I could have sworn there was an id named **mydropdown** :)

Comment: There is no element with ID "mydropdown".

Comment: I have more than one form on the page, so when submit is pressed, I need the value from `this` form. Updated the post with an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select[name="mydropdown"] option:selected').val()
```

UPDATE:

```
    $('form').live('submit', function(){

       var value_of_dropdown  = $(this).find('select[name="mydropdown"] option:selected').val();

       ...
  });
```

Comment: Can this be modified to work on `this` form? Have updated the post to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, just go for it like:

```
$('select').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name="mydropdown"]').change(function() {
   $('select[name="mydropdown"]').val();
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` at least, please. Don't repeat selectors.

Comment: Additionally, this is not what the OP asked for, and this code... does useless work.

Comment: sorry if i misread your requirements, yupp could have used this, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Get value selected with javascript:

```
var countsw=document.getElementById("controlid").options[document.getElement.getElementById("controlid").selectedIndex].value;
```

With this code you can get value selected combobox even if client-side control has this attribute `runat="server"` that use in server-side.